# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE bad response

Tags: mysql

Alright so I made some code that will insert some rows into SQL and if that row exist it will be updated.

Now my problem is
it should check if the weaponID exist, not the ID. 
So for example

How it should work?
There should be multiple rows of WeaponID's assigned persons ID's. There will be many rows (around 25 per player) but I cannot do it...

Im not sure how to explain what I want to achieve...
Basically User will have around 25 rows inside this table, but I want to UPDATE only if there is row with the same ID and WEAPON ID, if there aint, insert.

```
INSERT INTO `weapon_skills` VALUES (%d,'%e',%d, %d) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Skill`=%d
```

this is the structure

```
CREATE TABLE `weapon_skills` (
`ID` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`WeaponID` INT(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`Username` VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`Skill` INT(20) NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
```

Basically, if there is a row with for example ID: 0 and Weapon ID: 24 then update, if there isnt, create new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mysql documentation on [insert ... on duplicate key update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) says:

> If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, MySQL performs an UPDATE of the old row.

You should create a unique index on username and weaponid columns. If you try to insert a record for the same user with the same weapon that is in the table already, then the duplicate key clause will kick in. The id field should probably be an auto increment field, if needed at all.

Pls note that it would be more efficient to use a numeric user id field instead of the textual username to identify which user the record belongs to.

Unless your id field represents your user id. In this case add weapons id to the primary key instead of creating a unique key. But I would remove the username field from the table in this instance.

Comment: Yes! Thats it! Unique keys! Thanks a lot buddy!
Regarding they keys haha yeah, I used ID as UniqueID and WeaponID as indentifier. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

"on duplicate key update" will work only if the key is violated, so consider to alter the key by adding weaponID.

```
CREATE TABLE `weapon_skills` (
`ID` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`WeaponID` INT(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`Username` VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`Skill` INT(20) NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`,`WeaponID`)
```

If you don't want to alter the key, then consider to create a procedure in mySql to do it manually. You can also do it on backend level.